# how to get unique values of dictonaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am using dictionaries in python and below is my code

```
A.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
A.groupby('ID')[['VALUE']].apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('list')).to_dict()
```

output for the above code is:

```
 1:{'VALUE':['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a',.......]},
 2: {'VALUE': ['b','b','b',''b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b','b',.......]}
```

can anyone help me to get output in the following way

```
1: {'VALUE': ['a']}
2: {'VALUE': ['b']}
```

Comment: Write input data.

Comment: Use `set()` on `list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `dict` comprehension with `set` in value

**Ex:**

```
A.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
A.groupby('ID')[['VALUE']].apply(lambda x: {k: list(set(v)) for k, v in x.to_dict('list').items()}).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer pd.Series.unique

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "VALUE": ['a','a','a','a','a','a','a','a', 'b','b','b', 'b','b','b','b','b','b','b'],
    "ID": ([1] * 9 + [2] * 9)
})

df.groupby('ID')['VALUE'].apply(pd.Series.unique).apply(list).to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `set` to uniquify the elements. In python, `set` is a unique element collection which is unordered and unindexed.

I think, his example may help you.

```
d1={'value': ['a','a','a','b','b','c','a','c']}
val1 = set(list(d1.values())[0])
print(val1)
```

**Output**

```
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

You may also try this out.

```
val2 = set(d1.get('value')) 
print(val2)
```

**Output**

```
{'a', 'b', 'c'}
```